# Code works on Ide but not on server

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-scraping, visual-studio-2017, html-agility-pack

I am trying to write a aspx page for fun. And code is currently working on Ide side when i push it to the server i get this **error**:

*"error CS0103: The name 'doc' does not exist in the current context"*

*Source Error:*

```
Line 31:         Url = "https://www.********.com/";
Line 32:         HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
Line 33:         HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
Line 34: 
Line 35:         for (int q = 3; q < 5; q++)
```

I am using HtmlAgilityPack.And tried to change the string url to Uri but did not work :< What can I do?

Comment: Connectivity problems? Firewall, routing, DNS, etc..? Did you try to test telnet from the command line server to the URL?

Comment: the problem is with the Line:33

Comment: That's a very generic line of code. That problem be just about anything.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you upload the HtmlAgilityPack dll to the server.
Hmm, if line 32 works, you probably did that already.

You might be missing `string` before Url?

Edit:

try

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);
```

i think that's all you need.

http://html-agility-pack.net/from-web

Answer (score 0):

First it was about firewall from the hosting than yeah it turns out to be IDE is too smart and understands where HtmlDocument came from but for hosting i needed to define HtmlDocument at the top as 
    **HtmlDocument doc=new HtmlDocument();**
*solved my problem.*

Comment: So I was right in my comment. ;) At least one like to it, please.